# How to set ID of item when the item is not yet created..?

Tags: php, ajax

I'll try to make myself clear with an example:

Imagine an admin page to add a product to a database (product list). When I open the ADD ITEM page, the item is not yet created (not until I click the submit button), but let's say I want to add categories this product will appear in (with AJAX for example). When I run the AJAX script, i need to tell it which ID (my product) to put these categories in...

How should I do this.?

Is inserting a blank item in the database (to get mysql_insert_id) when the page opens a good way to do this.?  Is it prone to conflicts or errors..?

I'm afraid this technique will populate the DB with lots of empty product because of admins reloading the page, leaving the page before submitting, etc...

How do you guys do it.?

Comment: `i need to tell it which ID (my product) to put these categories in...` no, you don't need it. Just add categories after inserting product. What's the problem?

Comment: Any user that has a need to know the id in the database is an advanced user who should understand that it's best to only get the id after the insert. After you add it, you can feel free to tell them that "For your records, the entry as added with id $id"

Comment: I know I could do it as a 2-step process (add item - then redirect to add categories page).  I'm just trying to use AJAX as much as possible, when it makes sense...  I think that adding hidden input is probably my best bet...

Comment: I guess I don't follow you... I don't see why you would need to insert into the database to get what categories it will be in. Couldn't you just query for those based on input regardless of whether or not you create anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the categories via JS, don't post back to the php script, but add form elements to the page's form.  You can add hidden input elements with the name `category_id[]`.  That way, nothing is changed in the DB until you actually submit the item form.  Then, in the item controller in php, all you need to do is after adding the item, add the categories...

Answer (score 1):

I use a GUID as my IDs on stuff like this which you can generate on pretty much any system. (But use the libraries!)

Comment: I use GUIDs as well providing you do not need to display them to the user

Comment: @Rob Goodwin I never really present them with a unique ID unless it's necessary. I will, however, provide them a pseudoID for things like speed lookups. But that's just an indexable field.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with ircmaxell. You shouldn't be posting to the database until all your form elements are filled. You can use ajax or whatever to alter which form elements are displayed when, but its a good idea to make all your database inserts at once.

Comment: I think this is nonsense. Make database inserts when it makes good business sense to do so, otherwise you'll lose something along the way. However, I don't object to grouping the calls as effectively as possible. The database engine is a helluva lot more powerful than we tend to think it is (sure it's possible to overload it, but write things to be as efficient as they should be and tune the system LATER).